# Vector identity in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, vectors, vector-fields

I want to verify the right-hand side of $$(u\cdot\nabla)u=(\nabla\times u)\times u+\nabla(\frac{1}{2}u^2)$$ in cylindrical coordinates (the relation is given in a book on mechanics) for $u=u_\theta(r,t)e_\theta$ (basically only a $\theta$ component in $r$ and $t$). For the left-hand side the result is obvious $$(u\cdot\nabla)u=-\frac{{u_\theta}^2}{r}e_r$$
For the right-hand I got
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{u}
=\left(\boldsymbol{e_r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\boldsymbol{e_{\theta}}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\boldsymbol{e_z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\times\left(u_{\theta}\boldsymbol{e_{\theta}}\right)$$
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{u}
=\left(\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}+\frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\right)\boldsymbol{e_z}$$
then
$$(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{u})\times\boldsymbol{u}
=\left(\left(\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}+\frac{u_{\theta}}{r}\right)\boldsymbol{e_z}\right)\times(u_{\theta}\boldsymbol{e_{\theta}})$$
$$(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\boldsymbol{u})\times\boldsymbol{u}
=\left(-u_{\theta}\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}-\frac{{u_{\theta}}^2}{r}\right)\boldsymbol{e_r}$$
but I'm not sure how to get the second term $\nabla(\frac{1}{2}u^2)$. If I got the first term right then this should be $u_{\theta}\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}e_r$, except this doesn't seem to make sense because if $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ (from $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}e_r$ in $\nabla$) hits $u_\theta$ then the result will be zero because $e_r\cdot e_\theta=0$. Also wouldn't the divergence not be in terms of unit vectors anyway ? Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
(Edit: the $\boldsymbol{u}$ in question is a solution to the Navier Stokes equations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_\theta$ is a function of $r$.

$\frac{1}{2}u^2 = \frac{1}{2}(u_\theta^2(r,t) \vec{e_\theta} \cdot \vec{e_\theta}) = \frac{1}{2}u_\theta^2(r,t)$

then,

$\frac{d}{dr} (\frac{1}{2}u_\theta^2(r,t)) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dr} u_\theta^2(r,t) 
 = u_\theta \frac{d}{dr} u_\theta$ (by Leibniz rule)

Therefore,

$\nabla (\frac{1}{2} u^2) = u_\theta \frac{du_\theta}{dr}  \vec e_r$

Comment: ${e_{\theta}}^2=1$ of course- thanks a lot.

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630493/navier-stokes-equation-in-cylindrical-coordinates) question I had before remains unanswered on mathSE if you ever have time and are interested in responding.

Comment: @chb I upload. Thx